# What is the purpose of this Emberjs component's "update" action

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am looking at some legacy code from a previous EmberJS v2.16 project, the person responsible is not longer around, so I'm hoping for some advice here.

```
export default Component.extend({
  // ...

  actions: {
    update(value) {
      this.get('update')(value);
    },

  // ...
});
```

I'm not sure how much code is required, but let me know if it's too abstract and I'll try to provide more context.

Is `this.get('update')` referring to the `update(value)` function? In what situation will someone have to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Your developer probably wanted to execute an action outside of your component. When the component is invoked in your template I'm guessing it looks something like this.

```hbs
{{awesome-component update=(action 'outer-update-action')}}
```

So then in your component `this.get('update')` would get the function that was passed in so you can call it with your value.

It's described in the Ember Guide on the component page under "[Triggering Changes with Actions](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/)".